# Как вывести дату создания элемента в Bitrix?

Tags: php, битрикс

У меня есть таблица в которой формируется картинка-наименование товара-номер заказа. Мне в этой таблице нужно вывести дату создания товара. Использую

```
       $arParams["DATE_CREATE"]="j F Y";
    echo CIBlockFormatProperties::DateFormat($arParams["DATE_CREATE"],
 MakeTimeStamp($arElement["DATE_CREATE"], CSite::GetDateFormat()));
```

Но выводится дата 01.01.1970
В чем проблема?

Comment: А есть ли у вас в `$arElement["DATE_CREATE"]` вообще какая-то дата? У вас `DateFormat` приезжает 0 из `MakeTimeStamp`

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что строкой `$arParams["DATE_CREATE"]="j F Y";` вы затираете дату (если она конечно там была) указанной строкой. И в дальнейшем функция `MakeTimeStamp` получает в качестве параметра эту строку и распознает ее как некоректную строку.

По идее надо заменить код на следующий:

```
echo CIBlockFormatProperties::DateFormat("j F Y",
  MakeTimeStamp($arElement["DATE_CREATE"], CSite::GetDateFormat())
);
```

Comment: Не помогло, не могу понять а как он понимает адрес какого товара нужно выводить? У меня там везде массивы, ведь тут в запросе я не запрашиваю id товара если не ошибаюсь